# How to prevent longtable from tearing apart my text weirdly?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable

I have the problem, that as a german speaking person, words get rather long. Even with hyphenation tables usually gets torn apart. Is there an option to still have the automatic line-break options longtable gives me, without it formating that big of space in between the words? Like making my coulmns left centered in those cases?

[image: Help me prevent this space here]

"Minimal" Working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
left=2cm,
right=2cm,
top=3cm,
landscape=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} %kopfzeile
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.15\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}}
Phasen~der Bestand\-teile & Beispiel                         & Stoffgemischtyp & Art des Gemisches & Begründung der Einordnung\\ \hline
 & & & &\\ \hline
 & & & &\\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I normally set them ragged right.

Comment: It is just doing what you specfy, not anything built in to longtable. `p{0.1\textwidth}` is a narrow `\parbox` and you have the default justified text so tex has to maintain the left and right margin, over-stretching the white space is the  way there, use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.1\textwidth}` (and add the `array` package for the `>` syntax) to set the column ragged.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh I was very sure that it was a user problem. But I just didn't know better. Thank you so much for this solution!